# Link minimize/maximize/on top between parent/child app windows

Tags: window, window-manager, cinnamon, maximized

I run several apps split between two monitors and I'd love to have parent and child windows minimizing/maximizing and brought to top by each other as they behave in Windows. Anyone know if this is possible under Cinnamon?

Note that I'm NOT looking for a hotkey solution, this is about if an app window is active, it and any child windows - or the reverse, should be on top. And I get this might be impossible, but it's such a huge pain in my ***, windows not being linked. :(

And I have not found any solution anywhere. As a former Houdini LoCo TeamLeader, I have a fair bit of Linux experience, so it's not like I haven't digged into this pretty deeply before looking for help here.

Comment: I know that in Xfce4 the panel allows for Minimize All - Unminimize All when they are grouped together on the bar.

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult, but requires a backtound script. Would that be an acceptable solution to you?

Comment: The linked dupe takes care of raising all windows of an application. If maximizing *all* windows of an application is essential to you, please leave a message.

Comment: Jacob - any solution is acceptable, background daemon type stuff, it would just help me out so much not having to reprogram my brain here, my dual monitor workflow is just sooo ingrained after 1+ decades of splitting stuff between monitors... :)>

Edit: And minimizing/maximizing would be nice, raising to top is essential, though.

Comment: Did you try the linked one? It should do what you describe.

Comment: It doesn't work sadly. It states in the description for the daemon it only works on the current desktop - and it also didn't actually work, so that was a hint. ;) 

My fear is it's not possible, that it's the separate desktops itself that is the issue - though hoping I'm wrong. 

And this is on the level I will even jump do another window manager, if that's what I need to do.

Comment: I've now realized how this isn't that simple - it's also about how additional windows are created/what type they are in the coding. I noticed Nuke is behaving exactly as I want in Linux - though Nuke also doesn't show the window on my second monitor as a window with a window button, so I suspect it's a "floating panel" rather than an actual window....